# Android studio game quizz font

Tags: android

i have a quizz game in Android studio..
Everything works perfect but when someone have change the phone font to bigger,
it also changes the font in the game..Ηow can I turn it off so that the font is as it is set in the game, and not changes from the setting of the mobile phone?
I would appreciate a complete answer.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do this.  If they set the phone to a larger font, its because they're having trouble reading it.  This is an acessibility setting.  Counteracting that would be like tipping over a guy in a wheelchair.  Respect the user's choice, learn how to specify font sizes in sp, and if that makes your app slightly less pretty remember that an app that is ugly but readable will be used, an app they can't read is unusable.

Comment: Some phones have different default setting for font.. so i have build my game in small font of phone and it is very clearly and big.. I really need to disable to change the font from my game if the phone settings is changed cause people they complain that words are lost because they are big! i dont want phone and my app have connect about font..

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19628390)

Comment: @Rob no it provides the best answer. That is shouldn't be done. Not every answer is code, or an explanation on how to do it. A explanation of why not is every bit if not more valuable